# Visual Studio 2010 Editor UndoHistory

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to write an extension that can access the TextUndoHistory of an VS editor.

Do I have to implement ITextUndoHistory and ITextUndoTransaction myself or is there something that I can hook into using the SDK?

Thanks,
   Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You import an `ITextUndoHistoryRegistry` from an `[Export]`ed MEF component, and call `TryGetHistory` to retrieve the history for a given buffer.  See [MarginFactory.cs](http://github.com/NoahRic/FixMixedTabs/blob/master/MarginFactory.cs) from my [FixMixedTabs](http://github.com/NoahRic/FixMixedTabs) extension for an example (in that same extension, [InformationBar.cs](http://github.com/NoahRic/FixMixedTabs/blob/master/InformationBar.cs) shows you how to create transactions on the undo history).